# Source file generating in wrong package with lombok spring boot

Tags: lombok

Importing the lombok in gradle dependencies:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
group = 'com.kprotect'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '8'
ext {
    mapstructVersion = '1.4.2.Final'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation ("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapstructVersion}")
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.5.6'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:3.0.4'    
    implementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:3.1.2'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
    
    compileOnly "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"
    
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
 
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")   
    
      runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:2.0.202'
    
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**

then i am building my project like this:
./gradlew build   (from cmd)

this generated all the lombok files but in project they are showing the package issue:

[image]

Can you please guide me how to resolve this, I added the lombok.jar in eclipse also and enabled the annotation processing also:

[image]

Can you please guide me how get rid from this,
thanks in advance.